# plot() in R: ylim range don't match the y axis range on graph

Tags: r

I wanted to plot this:

```
plot( 0, 0, type = "n",xlim =c(-3, 3), ylim =c(-5, 5), xlab = "x", ylab = "y" )
```

However, on the graph, it shows the y axes range is not c(-5, 5) but c(-4,4).

Comment: you can get more control of the ticks by suppressing the axes in the plot command and using the `axis` function post-plot.

Comment: i.e. `plot( 0, 0, type = "n",xlim =c(-3, 3), ylim =c(-4, 4), xlab = "x", ylab = "y" , yaxt = 'n')
 axis(2,  -4:4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is based on the tick labels, we can do

```
plot( 0, 0, type = "n",xlim =c(-3, 3), ylim =c(-4, 4), 
        xlab = "x", ylab = "y" , yaxt = 'n')
axis(2,  -4:4)
```